# AKS cluster doesn't start after manually adding a node

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

After manually adding a node with an YAML, AKS cluster stopped working.

[image: node YAML]

The node doesn't appear on any of my node pools using az aks show or az aks nodepool.

The only information about the previous node is a troubleshooting obtained from node pools as shown in image below.

[image: only information about the node]

I tried to restart the cluster, but now it won't start either.

Any thoughts on this?